# Why new Promise.all().then() worked?

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

```
let iconsLoaded = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  new Promise.all(
    Object.keys(icons).map(iconName => {
      const Provider = icons[iconName][2] || defaultIconProvider; // Ionicons
      return Provider.getImageSource(
        iconName.replace(replaceSuffixPattern, ''),
        icons[iconName][0],
        icons[iconName][1]
      )
    })
  ).then(sources => {
    Object.keys(icons)
      .forEach((iconName, idx) => iconsMap[iconName] = sources[idx])

    // Call resolve (and we are done)
    resolve(true);
  })
});
```

Please help me understand above code about Promise.all()

I know this Promise object has an call() method,but as I know it's a static method, it should not be used as above,eg: new Promise.all(),but it give me no error. Why-why-why...

[Here is source code:](https://gist.github.com/dropfen/4a2209d7274788027f782e8655be198f)

the code above has no error

But, my code as following was wrong..give me an error

```
let p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.log('p2 body')
  resolve('p2 resolve')
})

let p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.log('p1 body')
  resolve('p1 resolve')
})

var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
   new Promise.all([p2,p1])
   .then(function(){
    console.log('all(p2, p1) then')
  })
    console.log('p body')
})
```

Comment: Promise in an object isn't it this can help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: You're confusing `(new Promise()).all()` and `new Promise().all()`. The first means "construct a Promise and invoke 'all' on that object", while the second is "invoke Promise.all() and then construct an instance of whatever function it returns".

Comment: the code above has no error

But, i wrote code as following was wrong..give me an error 
let p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
 console.log('fuck p2')
  resolve('p2 resolve')
})

let p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
 console.log('fuck p1')
  resolve('p1 resolve')
})

var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
   new Promise.all([p2,p1])
   .then(function(){
   console.log('fuck then')
  })
 console.log('fuck')
})

Comment: "*wrong..give me an error*" - **which** error? Please post it.

Comment: Which promise implementation (library) are you using?

Comment: Oh, and avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: here has an same question,,but no resolve  https://forums.meteor.com/t/difference-between-promise-returned-with-or-without-keyword-new/28433/2]

Comment: When I try the code at the top I get the same error: *"TypeError: Promise.all is not a constructor"*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains profanities.

Comment: Profanity removed per [meta recommendation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255188/1426891). acoder, please be mindful that professionals use this site at work, and that appropriate language may allow this question to get more positive attention.

Comment: oh,sorry and thanks